# Have any books has been written about Ripple and Litecoin?

Tags: blockchain, litecoin, ripple

I buy some ebooks about cryptocurrency, bitcoin and blockchain from 
http://sacredtraders.com/index.php/product-category/crypto-book

Have there been any books written about Ripple and Litecoin?

Answer (score 1):

I found a few books on Amazon that may interest you.

- [Ripple Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079ZQFCRK)
- [Generic book explaining Ripple](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076HL12X2)
- [Litecoin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0793L2HWD)

These books can be very generic.

For understanding the technology, I would recommend that you read the white-paper (yellow-paper if super interested).

1. [Whitepaper-Ripple](https://ripple.com/files/ripple_consensus_whitepaper.pdf)
2. [Solutions using Ripple](https://ripple.com/files/ripple_solutions_guide.pdf)
3. [Ripple whitepaper explained](https://hackernoon.com/whitepaper-in-four-minutes-ripple-a27103e4d265)

#### Video Resources

1. [Ripple consensus algorithm explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-4q4OjD_6w)
2. [Litecoin explained by its founder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2KP8koYC3s)

P.S. As of writing this answer, there's no official whitepaper for Litecoin, as it is a fork of Bitcoin and uses similar underlying technology with the claims of being faster than its predecessor.

Comment: I have gone through some of them mentioned above and found it to be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any books about Ripple.  However, you can purchase an introductory e-book for new cryptoinvestors on Litecoin from the Litecoin Foundation.

https://litecoin-foundation.org/product/understanding-litecoin-the-digital-currency-for-payments/